# Determining Which Tensorflow Op Implementation is Used

Tags: tensorflow

In my Tensorflow graph I have a `Conv2D` op. How can I tell which implementation is actually used when the graph is run? Tensorflow has [a number of implementations of this Op available](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/0be81439c91e297b078152dd0c266471b24bde7f/tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops.cc) and chooses one based on various optimization criteria, device and installed libs.

Comment: If you are lucky, do `export TF_CPP_MIN_VLOG_LEVEL=1` and the kernel will print a message that it's getting executed, don't know of any reliable way